# Sorting multidimensional array, descending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array in my ruby which looks like this :

```
arr= [{"10.0.1.50", "4"},
      {"10.0.1.51", "10"},
      {"10.0.1.48", "7"}]
```

I want to sort it such that the result should be:

```
result= [{"10.0.1.51", "10"},
         {"10.0.1.50", "4"},
         {"10.0.1.48", "7"}]
```

I am basically sorting on the first column which is 10.0.1.X. So it is sorted based on X.

Comment: Are you sorting based on left side "10.0.1.51" or right side "10"

Comment: @garbagecollection : The first column.....I just edited the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is not Ruby and the result is a bit ambiguous, but I guess you want something along the lines of

```
arr.sort_by { |(x,_)| x.split(".").map(&:to_i) }.reverse!
```

Comment: This does not work as the first column (10.0.1.X) is considered as a string. Is there any way I can convert that to float? If i do (.to_f) it will convert it to 10.0 ignoring everything else after it.

Comment: @sagar: You need to specify what order it is that you want to use for sorting. I'm guessing lexicographically, interpreting the dot-separated blocks as numbers? You wouldn't have these problems if you'd represent the IP addresses as what they are, 32-bit integers

Comment: It says : undefined method `to_i' for ["10.0.1.50"]:Array

Comment: @sogar: What's `arr`? I'm assuming `arr = [["10.0.1.50", "4"],["10.0.1.51", "10"],["10.0.1.48", "7"]]`. I don't see where the `["10.0.1.50"]` is coming from. Since your example code is no valid Ruby (Ruby has no syntax element of the form `{a_1,a_2,...,a_n}`) we can only guess.

Comment: arr_tmp = $connection.execute("select code_ver from builds;")

     arr = Array.new
     arr = arr_tmp.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |hash,element|
 hash[element] +=1
 hash }

Comment: @sagar: In that case, `arr` is not an array but a hash. Hashes have no inherent order, so you can't sort them. You could use `to_a` to convert it to an array that can be processed like I described it in my answer

Comment: By the way, the call to `Array.new` is totally superflous there. Also, `Array.new` is the same thing as `[]`.

Comment: Oh and consider using a better SQL statement here, that way you won't need the injection into a hash: `SELECT code_ver, COUNT(*) as num FROM builds GROUP BY code_ver`. You should never do these kinds of aggregations on the client side and waste computation time and network traffic, if you can do it on the DB server